# watch-companion in plist required by iTunesConnect, breaks Watch App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, watchos-2

I have an iOS+watchOS 2 app that I have been trying to submit to iTunesConnect. Upon submission, I get the error:

> Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key
>   ‘UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities’ in bundle
>   BBApp.app/Watch/BodBotWatchOS2.app/Plugins/BodBotWatchOS 2
>   Extension.appex is invalid. Expecting array with a single string value
>   of watch-companion.

I went ahead and added that value to my Watch App Extension's Info.plist, but found that it caused the Watch App to hang at launch (just my app name and the loading circle.) Removing it causes my Watch App to work, but I get the error again and can't submit it to iTunesConnect. I've done quite a bit of Googling/StackOverflowing To be honest, I don't really even know where to start on this, so even if someone doesn't have the end solution even pointing in a particular direction would be appreciated. I'm happy to provide additional information, but given my unfortunate lack of bearings here, I'm not sure what information is relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: this bit: array with a single string value of watch-companion -- are you adding an array containing the single value, or just the value?

Comment: I'm adding an array containing the single value, yes. Though I seem to have found a solution, detailed in the answer I've written for this question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to work is just completely removing the "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" value from my Watch App Extension's Info.plist file. It allows my Watch App to work and I am able to submit the app successfully. Haven't encountered any issues so far.